# How do I change position of the badge for a bottomTab?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation, velo, bottombar

I am able to change the position of bottomTab icon using

> iconInsets

like this

```
{
            stack: {
              children: [
                {
                  component: {
                    name: NOTIFICATIONS,
                    passProps: {
                      ...props,
                    },
                  },
                },
              ],
              options: {
                bottomTab: {
                  icon: NOTIFICATIONS_ICON,
                  iconColor: 'rgb(165, 165, 165)',
                  selectedIconColor: '#f57474',
                  iconInsets: {
                    top: 0,
                    left: 0,
                    bottom: hasNotch ? -25 : -10,
                    right: 0,
                  },
                },
              },
            },
          },
```

But the notification badge dosent change its position and there is a white space between icon and the badge as shown in the image below:

[image]

I have looked into the [react-native-navigation](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation) library and couldn't find any prop which can change the position of the badge as well.

It will be really helpful if anyone can share a solution to this issue thanks

Comment: Can u share ur code on [snack](https://snack.expo.io)

Comment: @DevAS its a huge app and won't be able to show you the code as well, but the issue is quite clear even with the description of my question if you have used react-native-navigation bottombar, I have changed the position of bottombar icons using iconInsets but the position of badge dosen't change with it. Do we have any workaround to change the position of badge as well?